# How can I specify a CollectionType for a generic struct/class?

Tags: swift

For example, say I have an struct `AdjacencyList` where I want to specify the type of container that the vertices are stored in such that the user can choose `Set` if they don't want duplicates, or `Array` if they do.

(I've omitted protocol conformances for the types since my example code is already incorrect as-is and many would have to be conformed to depending on the container type. For example, `Set` elements would need to be `Hashable`.)

```
public struct AdjacencyList<VertexType, EdgeType, VertexContainerType, EdgeContainerType> {
    var vertices: VertexContainerType<VertexType>
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please show us what did you tried to do that so far.

Comment: You are right, you would need to conform much of you code depending on the container type. Because of this, you may not want to use the same object for ordering via `Set`s and ordering via `Array`s. The problem is that the `CollectionType` protocol is not generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that `CollectionType` is not generic. One way around the specific issue you point out is to just have the client specify the container types and then you can extract the actual element types.

For example:

```
struct AdjacencyList<VertexContainerType: CollectionType, EdgeContainerType: CollectionType> {

    var vertices: VertexContainerType

    typealias VertexType = VertexContainerType.Generator.Element

    typealias EdgeType = EdgeContainerType.Generator.Element

    func printTypes() {
        print("VertexType: \(VertexType.self)\nEdgeType: \(EdgeType.self)")

    }

}

let a = AdjacencyList<Array<Int>, Array<Double>>(vertices: [Int]())

a.printTypes()

// Prints:
// VertexType: Int
// EdgeType: Double
```